# Calculate sum of values in column

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How to calculate sum of all values in a column and display it in a label.content.

Creating a column:

```
    Dim c7 As New DataGridTextColumn()
    c7.Header = "Iznos"
    c7.Width = 100
    c7.Binding = New Binding("Iznos")
    gridRacun.Columns.Add(c7)
```

Class for creating items:

```
Class Item
Private _Cijena As String
Private _Rabat As String
Private _PC As String
Private _Iznos As String



Property Kolicina() As Integer
    Get
        Return _Kolicina
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        Me._Kolicina = value
    End Set
End Property
Property Cijena() As Decimal
    Get
        Return _Cijena
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        Me._Cijena = value
    End Set
End Property

Property Iznos() As Decimal
    Get
        Return _Iznos
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        Me._Iznos = Me._Kolicina * Me.Cijena
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Adding items to datagrid:

```
     Dim item = New Item With {.Cijena = Globals.cijenaTempG, .Rabat = Globals.rabatG, .PC = 1.0, .Iznos = 1.0}
    gridRacun.Items.Add(item)
```

I want to calculate SUM of column named "Iznos" and display it in labelSum.content

Comment: You could calculate the sum when you adding the items to the `DataGrid`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could iterate over the rows of the datagridview and calculate the sum

```
dim sum = 0  
for each row as datagridviewrow in gricRacun.rows  
 dim cellValue  as double 
if not double.tryparse(row.cells(c7.index).value,cellValue) then cellValue = 0  
sum += cellValue  
next row
```

you could trigger it in text change event and other event and assign where you wanted

Answer (score 0):

The column is bound to a property of the items. Sum the properties and expose that to the view instead of focusing on the grid itself.

```
' Calculate the sum (using Linq).
Dim sum = gridRacun.Items.OfType(Of Item)().Sum(Function(item) item.Iznos)
' Update the label.
labelSum.Content = sum
```

Now all that is left is to figure out when to trigger the calculation. Try listening to when the collection changes or if the property in question of any of the items are updated.